# Best way to randomize two identical arrays without overlap?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, random

Suppose we have two identical arrays `{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}`. Is there a quick way to randomize the order of each that ensures when the two are lined up, the same letters are never at the same indices? (Obviously we can just generate a new index if it will cause a match but I'm wondering if there's a way that produces less repetition).

Comment: What is this used for?  And can you please be more specific about what you want the results to be?  As in, which permutations should be rejected by the rule that separates this from a simple "how do I shuffle two arrays?" question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, and I think it is fairly easy to understand.

```
var source = new [] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };

var output1 = (string[])null;
var output2 = (string[])null;

var rnd = new Random();
Action shuffle = () =>
{
    output1 = source.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
    output2 = source.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
};

shuffle();
while (output1.Zip(output2, (o1, o2) => new { o1, o2 })
    .Where(x => x.o1 == x.o2)
    .Any())
{
    shuffle();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that sorting by a random key is a good idea? I would assume say that in the general case, depending on a particular `OrderBy` implementation, it may lead to biased distribution or even to crashes.

Comment: @AlexD - Yes, this is a good idea. It's perfectly safe - no crashes. And I have done a distribution analysis in the past and it produces a uniform distribution.

Comment: Well, then we are just checking one concrete implementation, right? It may be stable and uniform. My concern is that there are no promises that the implementation is going to be the same always. Besides that, it is perhaps `O(N*log(N))` instead of `O(N)`.

Comment: @AlexD - No, I checked several implementations - including Fisher-Yates, and some other biased sorts - for comparison. Sorting this way is good. Also there is a fairly iron-clad promise that this implementation of `.OrderBy` will not change (unless there is a bug discovered in it). Microsoft is loath to make changes to the point that when Roslyn was developed they re-implemented the original compiler bugs.

Comment: The original question asked if there was "a way that produces less repetition", which I assume means to avoid re-rolling like you're doing here.  It's a bit vague, though.

Comment: @JoeAmenta - I don't see that there is any way to avoid re-rolling. I suspect that there is a more computationally efficient method than mine, but I know that with random selection you'd need to perform some sort of rollback when a clash occurs. I think my solution is just easier to understand than most and if it comes down to the difference between 10ms and 100ms then I'm not overly fussed.

Comment: @Enigmativity: for an array of length N, a given candidate result selected by your algorithm seems to have a 1/N chance of being accepted, which means what is likely to be an unacceptable (and unpredictable) number of re-rolls once the array length gets REALLY long.  Unless I'm overlooking something, my answer is a way to do it in at most (2N - 1) rolls, without any re-rolls, where N is the length of each array.

Comment: @JoeAmenta - I ran a trial with an array of length 52 (upper- and lower-case letters) over 10,000 runs and an average number of shuffles per run of 2.7. So if I get 10,000 accepted for 27,000 iterations then I've got a 37% chance of acceptance. If I change my source length to 520 then the same probability exists. It seems that it is independent of length.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Indeed, I'm wrong.  The calculation I used to figure out the probability of needing to re-roll was naïve... OK, no, that's being too nice to myself, it was flat-out BS.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in two steps with `O(n)` complexity.

**[Step 1]**
Shuffle just one array in a way that every letter changes its original position, something like this:

```
var rnd = new Random(0);
var x = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
for(int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
    var j0 = (i == x[i] - 'A')? i + 1: i;
    var j = rnd.Next(j0, x.Length);
    // x[i] ⟷ x[j]
    var t = x[i]; x[i] = x[j]; x[j] = t;
}
```

It ensures that the first and the second arrays are different in every position.

---

**[Step 2]**
Use [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for *both arrays synchronously*:

```
var y = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
for(int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
    var j = rnd.Next(i, x.Length);
    // x[i] ⟷ x[j]; y[i] ⟷ y[j]
    var
    t = x[i]; x[i] = x[j]; x[j] = t;
    t = y[i]; y[i] = y[j]; y[j] = t;
}
```

It ensures randomization of both, keeping difference at every position.

Comment: The second algorithm exhibits the exact problem @HEATH3N was trying to avoid: same letters at the same indices in both arrays. Technically it's a requirement the first solution doesn't address either as both arrays shuffled randomly will still end up with the same letter at the same index periodically.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy "_The second algorithm exhibits the exact problem_" Do you mean the step 2? How could it happen? After the step 1, the arrays are different at any position. And during step 2, the "pairs" `x[i], y[i]` stay unchanged, they just change their position.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't read carefully enough and thought these were two distinct solutions when in fact they're two steps of the same solution.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy I think it could be misleading indeed. Updated to make it more prominent.

Comment: Might be slightly clearer and more efficient to shuffle one array, then copy that and re-shuffle the copy excluding original positions.

Comment: @sh1 Yes, it looks slightly faster indeed. But still `O(n)` of course.

Answer (score 0):

My best advice would be to make your own randomizer method that takes 2 arguments: array to be shuffled and array that its not allowed to match.

Here is a quick example of a class that has 2 string arrays that it will be shuffling by calling (objectName).Shuffle();

```
public class ArrayShuffler {
    public String[] arr1;
    public String[] arr2;

    public ArrayShuffler() {
        arr1 = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
        arr2 = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
    }
    public void Shuffle() {
        shuffleArr(arr1);
        shuffleArr(arr2, arr1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Can shuffle array, maching against a second array to prevent dublicates in same intex spot.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="arr">Array to be shuffled</param>
    /// <param name="validate">Array to mach against</param>
    private void shuffleArr(String[] arr, String[] validate = null) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int indx = 0;
        while(indx < arr.Length){
            int rIndx = r.Next(indx, arr.Length);
            string tmp = arr[indx];
            if(validate != null) { //Will only be performed if you specify an array to be matched against.
                if(arr[rIndx] != validate[indx]) {
                    arr[indx] = arr[rIndx];
                    arr[rIndx] = tmp;
                    indx++;
                }
                else if(indx == arr.Length - 1) {
                    shuffleArr(arr, validate);
                }
            }
            else { //Default operation
                arr[indx] = arr[rIndx];
                arr[rIndx] = tmp;
                indx++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's say that `rIndx` always happens to be equal to `indx`. Are not we end up with two unchanged arrays then, which match at every position?

Comment: If value at `rIndx` always happens to be equal to `indx` you have a little bad luck on your hands, but you are right and I will edit the code to overcome this issue

Comment: Now let's say that shuffled `arr1` is still `A, B, C`. And let's say that when we shuffle first two elements of `arr2`, we get `B, A`. Will not it result in the endless loop? We cannot finish with `arr2`, since its last element always collides with the last element of `arr1`.

Comment: Added an "else if", if the validation fails on the last index it will try again. Not particularly effective but it gets the job done. (note: Not yet tested)

Comment: Please don't do `Random r = new Random();` inside a method - it may suffer from repeating values if the method is called quickly in succession. It's always best to create a field-level (and even better thread static) variable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to minimize the quantity of unnecessary re-rolls, and that it's the **two results** that must not match **one another** (permitting an output character at a particular index to match the character in the input at that index), I think I've got a solution for you.

The gist of it is that we build the resulting strings on-the-fly keeping track of which characters have not been picked in each list and temporarily removing the one we picked first for a particular index from the candidates we select from for the second one.  I don't think this method has any bias to it, but I'm admittedly not an expert in that regard.

```
public void Shuffle(int seed)
{
    char[] orig = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
    List<char> buffer1 = new List<char>();
    List<char> buffer2 = new List<char>();

    // Keep track of which indexes haven't yet been used in each buffer.
    List<int> availableIndexes1 = new List<int>(orig.Length);
    List<int> availableIndexes2 = new List<int>(orig.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < orig.Length; i++)
    {
        availableIndexes1.Add(i);
        availableIndexes2.Add(i);
    }

    Random rand = new Random(seed);

    // Treat the last 2 specially.  See after the loop for details.
    for (int i = 0; i < orig.Length - 2; i++)
    {
        // Choose an arbitrary available index for the first buffer.
        int rand1 = rand.Next(availableIndexes1.Count);

        int index1 = availableIndexes1[rand1];

        // Temporarily remove that index from the available indices for the second buffer.
        // We'll add it back in after if we removed it (note that it's not guaranteed to be there).
        bool removed = availableIndexes2.Remove(index1);
        int rand2 = rand.Next(availableIndexes2.Count);
        int index2 = availableIndexes2[rand2];
        if (removed)
        {
            availableIndexes2.Add(index1);
        }

        // Add the characters we selected at the corresponding indices to their respective buffers.
        buffer1.Add(orig[index1]);
        buffer2.Add(orig[index2]);

        // Remove the indices we used from the pool.
        availableIndexes1.RemoveAt(rand1);
        availableIndexes2.RemoveAt(rand2);
    }

    // At this point, we have 2 characters remaining to add to each buffer.  We have to be careful!
    // If we didn't do anything special, then we'd end up with the last characters matching.
    // So instead, we just flip up to a fixed number of coins to figure out the swaps that we need to do.
    int secondToLastIndex1Desired = rand.Next(2);
    int secondToLastIndex2Desired = rand.Next(2);

    // If the "desired" (i.e., randomly chosen) orders for the last two items in each buffer would clash...
    if (availableIndexes1[secondToLastIndex1Desired] == availableIndexes1[secondToLastIndex2Desired] ||
        availableIndexes1[(secondToLastIndex1Desired + 1) % 2] == availableIndexes2[(secondToLastIndex2Desired + 1) % 2])
    {
        // ...then swap the relative order of the last two elements in one of the two buffers.
        // The buffer whose elements we swap is also chosen at random.
        if (rand.Next(2) == 0)
        {
            secondToLastIndex1Desired = (secondToLastIndex1Desired + 1) % 2;
        }
        else
        {
            secondToLastIndex2Desired = (secondToLastIndex2Desired + 1) % 2;
        }
    }
    else if (rand.Next(2) == 0)
    {
        // Swap the last two elements in half of all cases where there's no clash to remove an affinity
        // that the last element has for the last index of the output, and an affinity that the first
        // element has for the second-to-last index of the output.
        int t = secondToLastIndex1Desired;
        secondToLastIndex1Desired = secondToLastIndex2Desired;
        secondToLastIndex2Desired = t;
    }

    buffer1.Add(orig[availableIndexes1[secondToLastIndex1Desired]]);
    buffer1.Add(orig[availableIndexes1[(secondToLastIndex1Desired + 1) % 2]]);

    buffer2.Add(orig[availableIndexes2[secondToLastIndex2Desired]]);
    buffer2.Add(orig[availableIndexes2[(secondToLastIndex2Desired + 1) % 2]]);

    Console.WriteLine(new string(buffer1.ToArray()));
    Console.WriteLine(new string(buffer2.ToArray()));
}
```

Note that if this were used for *particularly* long arrays, then the data moving from `List<T>.Remove` / `List<T>.RemoveAt` and the linear searching done by the former may not scale well.

Comment: I tested your code and you have a bias on the last two elements of the output. I ran 10,000,000 iterations from a sequence of 10 characters (`a` to `j`) and then did a frequency analysis of the characters in the source. `a` was evenly distributed over the first 8 slots, but was 4% more likely to be in the penultimate slot and 4% less likely in the last slot. `j` was also evenly distributed in the first 8, but was 4% less likely in the penultimate slot and 4% more likely in the last. It basically flipped from the `a`.

Comment: @Enigmativity: thanks for testing it -- I just repeated your test and got the same results.  I'm admittedly unsure about *exactly* why these affinities exist, but I did determine (using actual testing this time... gasp!) that swapping the last two elements in the "no clash" case 50% of the time removes this specific bias entirely, and an unscientific look at the results of the same 10,000,000 test (it's been a while since my single university stats class, so I don't want to pretend I did it right, even though it feels good to me) suggests that there's no letter / position bias anymore.

Comment: I kept my test code so I'll retest later and let you know my results. Cheers.